# Как создать массив разных классов?

Tags: java

У меня такая задача что в ней нужно как то закинуть мои классы а их 5 штук в массив. После этого производится некая операция которая решает какие классы нужны. в итоге из 5 будут только 2 или 3. И главное не попорядку.

А Б В Г Д. Может быть так что мне нужны будут только А В Д, Или Б В Д. Или А Д.

Единственное решение для меня это добавить мои классы в массив но не создавать их. Тобишь должно быть так. mas[]={A(), B(), C()}; и т.д.

Чтобы после я сделал так new mas[0]; Можно ли сие чудо как нибудь реализовать в программном виде?

Comment: А вот нас в школе учили, что **класс** -  это один из множества абстрактных типов данных в ООП, а **объект** - это *экземпляр* класса. Поэтому "классы закидывать в массив" как-то некорректно ;-)

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown, Дак я же класс не добавляю в массив)), Я имя добавлю Чтобы потом запустить тот или иной класс. Ведь код то у меня динамический. Был бы статическим я бы switch испольовал и все дела.

Comment: «Это все обман, чтобы набрать классы» :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1: в лоб**

В массив кладём объекты классов:

```
Class classes[] = { A.class, B.class, C.class, ... };
```

После выбора нужного класса создаём его экземпляр через Reflections API:

```
Сlass clazz = classes[index];
Constructor defaultConstructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
Object obj = defaultConstructor.newInstance();
```

Плюс этого метода - краткость. Минусы - отсутствие гибкости (создание объектов только через конструктор по умолчанию, невозможность кастомизации процесса создания), скорость (Reflections API достаточно медленный, если вы будете создавать таким методом большое количество объектов - вы это почувствуете).

**Вариант 2: фабрики**

Реализуем шаблон проектирования "[Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)". Для этого создаём класс `ObjectFactory`:

```
public abstract class ObjectFactory {
    // Метод createObject должен возвращать общего предка всех создаваемых классов.
    // Так как вы ничего не сказали о своей иерархии,
    // я для приера взял Object как предка всех классов в Java.

    public Object createObject();
}
```

Для каждого класса, который необходимо создать, создаём наследника `ObjectFactory`, создающего экземпляр этого класса:

```
public class AFactory extends ObjectFactory {
    public Object createObject() {
        A a = new A();
        // дополнительные манипуляции по созданию экземпляра класса A
        return a;
    }
}

public class BFactory extends ObjectFactory {
    public Object createObject() {
        B b = new B();
        // дополнительные манипуляции по созданию экземпляра класса B
        return b;
    }
}

...
```

Создаём массив фабрик:

```
ObjectFactory factories[] = { new AFactory(), new BFactory(), ... };
```

Выбрав нужную фабрику, создаём объект нужного класса:

```
ObjectFactory factory = factories[index];
Object obj = factory.createObject();
```

Плюсы: отсутствие требований к конструкторам создаваемых классов и возможность настройки процесса создания объектов. Минус: больший объём кода по сравнению с первым методом.

Наиболее предпочтительным является второй метод, так как он даёт больше контроля над процессом создания экземпляров классов.

Comment: Первый способ что надо. Дайте пожалуйста объясните  методов 1 способа

Comment: Во-первых, всё-таки подумайте над применением второго сопособа. Испольование Reflections API вне инструментов и фреймвороков в Java нежелательно. Во-вторых, что именно вам непонятно в методах первого способа? Попробуйте для начала почитать их документацию ([раз](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), [два](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html)).

Comment: Почему мне 1 способ удобнее, потому что мне объекты не нужны, Мне нужно просто запустить грубо говоря последовательно максимум 12 классов. А каждый класс он выполняет свою работу. Но запускаю я их последовательно

Comment: Мне немного не ясно вот это
А чем отличается "new", от 
"Constructor defaultConstructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor();
defaultConstructor.newInstance();"?

Comment: Отличие в том, что когда вы используете оператор `new`, вы уже в момент компиляции должны знать, экземпляр какого класса вы хотите создать. А Reflections API предназначен для манипуляций с классами, о которых мы в момент компиляции не знаем ничего, и что-то выяснить можем только во время выполнения программы.

Comment: Как пример правильного использования Reflections API - библиотеки вроде Spring, позволяющие создавать объекты, имена классов и значения полей которых описаны в XML-конфигурации, и, соответственно,  неизвестны компилятору. Или любая IDE при помощи Reflections API может посмотреть список полей и методов любого класса. Или написание системы плагинов для приложения. Использование же Reflections API для повседневных нужд - "читерство", так как идёт вразрез с принципами ООП, на которых построена Java.

Comment: Ну вот, Значит именно 1 способ мне и нужен. Так как я просто создаю классы но не во время компиляции