# EntityManager получение нужного экземпляра entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Например: есть AutoRepository, сущность Auto и его наследники Car и Bus. Нужно, чтобы EntityManager возвращал результат запроса с экземплярами в зависимости от типа Auto.getType() (Car или Bus). Как это грамотно сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать массив разных классов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439692/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стратегия наследования InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE - это то что нужно
https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/singleinheritance/single.html